# How to only run tests in a TestSuite class with gradle wrapper command

Tags: java, gradle, junit, gradlew

I have a testSuite class:

```
package com.company.tests;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

import com.company.tests.facing.CustomerTests;
import com.company.tests.backend.BookTests;
import com.company.tests.backend.ChargeTests;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
CustomerTests.class,
BookTests.class,
ChargeTests.class,
})

public class TestSuite {
}
```

I use a gradle wrapper to run the tests as follows:

`./gradlew test -PTestSuite`

...but this runs **ALL** tests under /src/test/java/com/company/tests/

**Is there a way I can run JUST the ones in TestSuite class using gradle wrapper** from commandline? I looked at other questions on stackoverflow but couldn't work out, Please give an example.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510201. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by running the following:

```
./gradlew test --tests TestSuite
```

And the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/java_testing.html#simple_name_pattern) provides information about the kind of matching it supports.
Note that this assumes Gradle `4.7+`.

Comment: It does not work. Completes in 1 second and It will give the following output: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date`

Comment: So it works now. I had to make sure the TestSuite is on the same directory level as other tests. I put it under a folder called suite. Otherwise it runs TestSuite and all others under it. Also command I used is `./gradlew :test --tests "*suite.TestSuite"`