# How to run a j unit test suite using gradle

Tags: gradle, test-suite

So I have a test suite written in JUnit, like below, basic mantra is that all the test cases which are listed in @Suite.SuiteClasses are going to be included in for running of the tests.

```
package bddDemo.TestSuite;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ 
    //serenityBDDDemo.features.calculator.MathsUsingAnAngularCalculator.class,
    //serenityBDDDemo.features.API.automateRESTAPI.class 

})

public class TestSuite {

}
```

This runs perfectly well in maven, I can do mvn clean verify and what not, but when I tried to convert this project to a Gradle project, suite is not run, instead all the tests are run, weather are not marked for inclusion for running in the suite(which is kinda embarrassing).

Can you suggest a way to mark few tests cases for running and make a test suite in a gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a test suite using gradle from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789839/how-can-i-run-a-test-suite-using-gradle-from-the-command-line)

Comment: The answer to the linked question did not solve my problem. Thank you